# Radeon HD 6700G Windows 2012 server

Tags: drivers, amd-radeon, windows-server-2012

Hi I am unable to find the HD6900G driver for windows 2012 server. Does Someone have a link to the correct driver which adds hdmi support

Comment: Try the driver for Windows Vista or Windows 7

Comment: @Jakke - Why would he use Windows Vista/Windows 7 drivers on a Windows 8 Server platform?

Comment: Because if those Windows 8 platform drivers are not available, the other ones will work just as well. I've had to update several old computers that had no Windows 8 support and the Vista / 7 drivers did the job every single time.

Comment: http://www.pcpro.co.uk/blogs/2012/08/06/getting-older-drivers-to-work-in-windows-8/

Comment: @Jake do you no where I can download them from ?